# which is the safest way to include a pair of key (public/private) in a apk

Tags: android, security, apk

I'm developing an application for android and I have to maintain a secure communication with a server through a pair of private and public key. Which is the safest way to storage the private key in my apk? Obviously I'm going to obfuscate the code but I want more security. I have thought the following option:

If I create a native share library with the methods for sign the transaction information, The apk only have to contain the .so file and this file is in machine code, so the decompilation could be difficult, isn't it?

any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Who is the attacker in your threat model? The legitimate user of your device?

Comment: The attacker will not the user, the problem is that the app will access to a payment services and we want a secure app. In a simple apk anyone can decompile, get the keys and use them to access to the payment system

Comment: You should design your application in a way that a user who has the full source code of the application and all embedded keys can't do anything evil.

Answer (score 5):

Store the keypair in a **keystore** and include the keystore as a resource in your APK. Android tends to prefer the **BouncyCastle Key Store (BKS)** format. Keystores are specifically designed for this purpose.

Note that you should protect the keystore with a password and your application will need to know that password to access the keystore. So, you're left with needing to ask the user for a password to access the keystore or include the password in your code (obfuscate it to make it harder for an attacker to reverse engineer). If someone is going to the trouble of reverse engineering your application to recover your encrypted keystore and the password needed to access it, including that password in a compiled native library will not present much of an additional hurdle.

However, you may not need to do this anyway. If your goal is to protect/encrypt the data in transport to/from the server, use SSL/TLS. If you're not doing client-side authentication, your server needs an SSL certificate but your client does not; the protocol takes care of generating the encryption keys for you in a safe manner. If you do want the server to authenticate the client (make it so your server only talks to your clients), you'd need to install a client-side SSL certificate with your app ... this is the private key that you're probably thinking about.

I'll also point you to [Application Security for the Android Platform](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022596.do). This book (disclaimer: I wrote the book) has an entire chapter talking about how to design secure Android app-to-server communications, with code examples to illustrate how to implement the appropriate protections. You may want to give it a read.

Comment: Your response have opened different ways to solve the problem. In spite of obfuscation, I think that the password for the keystore is still visible in the code, so it isn't difficult to get the access to the keystore.

Comment: That's true. However...that's the best there is. If your client app that is running on the device needs access to something that it stores, a person with access to that device will be able to access it as well. All you can do it make it more difficult. Of course, you could not store the password and force the user to type it in everytime you need to access the keys. Not an ideal UX, but that password has to come from somewhere.

Comment: This is a big deal! I need to protect the client side certificate. The app is for buying and all transactions between the client (anyone that use the app) and server must be signed. I'm afraid that anyone can extract the certificate and start to send valid transactions to the server.

Comment: Then you need to ask the user for the password to the keystore on every transaction. You need to design your app/system with the assumption that anything contained in your application APK is recoverable by someone that wants to put forth the time/effort to do so. Because that assumption is true.

Comment: How about getting a password for the keystore from a scanned QR code that you send to users via post "like banks do" or just show it on your server under SSL when user is registering. You can do this only once per app install and it's more user friendly. Think about the way Google authorises Google glass for access to your account.

Comment: You don't need to ask for the password every time. Once is enough. Once you get the password from the user, you can extract out the key and store it in the Android Keystore. Once it is in the Android Keystore, it is secure. Only your app will be able to access your keys in the AndroidKeystore

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in order to implement secure communication between your client application and a server, conceptually speaking, you need only the public key of the server. That allows you to establish a one-way trust relation ship with the server and to establish a secure session, in which the identity of the server is guaranteed.

While certainly the above method does not provide two-way trust (the client cannot be identified to the server), when establishing the communication channel in most applications, this level of trust is not really required.

If your requirements are to provide client authentication to the server using public/private keys then things get more complicated because if you put the key in the apk, no matter how much you obfuscate it (including embedding it in a native library) it will only slow down a dedicated nefarious user.

The only way to store the private key with the client is to encrypt it. But then you have a similar issue of where to store the decrypt key. The easiest solution is to generate a public/private key pair for the user of the client application and ask the user to provide a symmetric encryption/decryption key (which the user will always have to type in) to decrypt the private key each time the user is using the application.

The alternative would be to use some kind of dedicated cryptographic hardware device similar to a smart card that would store the private key securely but you still have the problem of authorizing your application to read the key from the device (not to mention the complication of interfacing with said device).

Now, the question you have to ask yourself is this: *"Who are you trying to prevent from reading the private key?"* (of course after answering the other question: *"Do you really need a public/private key pair for the client"*).

Comment: The client side public/private key it's forced by the server side. I have to calculate the hash of the data, then codificate the hash with the private key and send my datas, the result of hash and the public key to the server. This is my main problem, how can I protect the private key!! :)

Comment: @rdiaz82, in that case you can most likely generate a new public/private key for the session. This way the private key is generated at run time and recycled for each session. That is unless the server somehow needs a copy of the client's public key to be registered in advance.

Comment: The private key in such a scenario is usually the one generated to identify the user of the app, not the same as the public key used for encrypting responses to the server.  In this case, the key should be stored on the device after generation as it is the user's key.